# How to avoid cramps during beach volleyball tournament (extreme hot weather)

Tags: cramps

Just a quick question when summer came.

I usually play 5 to 6 matches on beach volleyball tournaments and there is 35 Celsius degrees in the shadow but of course there is no shadow on the field. Sometimes you can even burn your feets by hot sand if you are not using neoprene socks.

For example last 2 matches I usually experience cramps in my calfs. So many full-power jumps during last 4 matches cruelly decided.

How to alleviate these? Do you use any special drinks during such an excessive performance (instead of hypotonic iont drinks and a lot of water)? Salt? Magnesium?

I know harder training can help here but what can I do in terms of supplementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eat something with a lot of potassium.... Like a banana.  Th potassium [stops cramps](http://macdonnellj.hubpages.com/hub/Does-Potassium-prevents-muscle-cramps). My uncle's doctor even told him to eat a banana a day because he was getting such bad cramps.

Comment: hmmm looks simple, nice and naturaly! That's exactly what I'm looking for. I'll try this this Saturday and will let you know. Thanks for the link.